# Лишний проход цикла

Tags: c, циклы

Здравствуйте!

Написал код, который рисует фигурку из букв. Но при проходе 1-го цикла, есть лишние проходы. Почему? Где ошибка?  Фигурка рисуется верно.

Требуемая фигура:

```
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i,j;
    i = 'f';
    while(i >= 'A')
    {
        for (j = 'F'; j >= i; j--)
            {
                printf("%c", j);        
            }
        i--;
        printf("\n");
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: вижу учитесь программировать - это хорошо. Хочу дать маленький совет обычно программист ставит перед собой точную цель-задачу (вы это сделали расплывчато - все участники сей час гадают какую фигуру вы хотели увидеть на консоли и в каком месте), обычно у программы-задачи есть входные параметры по каким оно решается (их нет), свои вопросы надо ставить корректно что бы другим они стали ясными.

Comment: @perfect, Всё верно. Спасибо за совет, не хотел писать полностью условие, т.к. боялся, что скажут мол сам не хочешь решать/думать.


Если кому интересно, то я хочу/могу учиться и участвовать в проектах(ищу типа наставника :)). Пишите мне в скайп(см. в профиле).

Comment: даже если это учебное задание и вы приложили к нему свое решения то никто вас не осудит ведь вы же думали и пытались решить свою задачу самостоятельно вам просто подскажут где вы ошибаетесь или я не прав?

Comment: @perfect, Вы правы.

PS Только учусь я сам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строку `i = 'f'` на  `i = 'F'` и вспомните/узнайте о том, что символы прописных букв != символам строчных, как, собственно, и их коды

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо.